# how to increase document quality after loading Pdf document using Pdfbox java

Tags: java, pdfbox

when i load and display pdf document using Pdfbox java API. But the document quality very very poor. the font is not very clear i don't know what i do with that(the first image is orginal document and the next is new document after loading )

here is the code

```
doc = PDDocument.load ( currentFile );
page = ( PDPage ) doc.getDocumentCatalog ().getAllPages ().get (      currantePage );
totalPage = doc.getNumberOfPages ();
wrapper.displayPage ( page );
scrollPaneDisplay.setViewportView ( wrapper.getPanel () );
```

[image: Orginal document]

[image: new document after loading using Pdfbox]

Comment: It seems to be a font problem. Try specifying the used fonts to the JVM...

Comment: What version are you using? And where does `wrapper` come from? Can you share your PDF, i.e. link to it?

Comment: I use Pdfbox 1.8.13 and wrapper is an object of PageWrapper class

Comment: PDFBox 1.8.13 has a lot of issues with rendering, I suggest you try 2.0.7. It has no wrapper class (the old PDFReader application has been removed due to many troubles), but you can try the code in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3359 . Or run the PDFDebugger command line application and use its source code for your own application.